# Docker, paths, json-file not found: not found

Tags: json, reactjs, docker, dockerfile, package.json

What is the problem? everytime happens this...

```
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR ../app                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => ERROR [3/5] COPY package.json .                                                                                                                           0.0s 
------
 > [3/5] COPY package.json .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/package.json" not found: not found
```

[image: [this is my filepaths] https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg9nS.png]

I can`t understand what am I doing wrong.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY ../app/package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I use `docker build .` in powershell

Comment: i think its prefered to display your Dockerfile and your shell command in Code section instead of adding pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include files from outside your context (the current directory you are in) to a docker image

So you can either move your `app` directory on the host to the folder of the `Dockerfile` or

You can do the following

```
docker build -f docker\Dockerfile .
```

in the *parent directory* (ie the directory containing the `docker` and the `app` folders). And adjust your Dockerfile as follows

```
COPY app/package.json .
```

Comment: I tryed, it not works, may be you can help me in discord or googlemeets?

Comment: I create folder app and folder docker
after I do `cd app` and do this `npx create-react-app` .
after I do this `cd ..` and `cd docker`
after I create Dockerfile from like from this post
and I do last thing `docker build .`  and after error

Comment: Sorry, what was I thinking ... I totally forgot, you cannot add files from outside your context (roughly speaking your current directory) to the docker image ...  please see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, i tryed and project was builded, but i got a new problem i do `docker ps` and there no anything...

Comment: localhost:3000 not working, server not starting :(

Comment: `docker build` does only build the image. If you want to run a container, you need to use [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: ok, i do `docker run [image id]` and it 
  `Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /app/public`

But index.html exists in app

What the problem?

Comment: Did you adapt your `COPY . . ` in the `Dockerfile` to `COPY app/ .`? Otherwise your `app` folder from the host won't be copied ...

Comment: I change a `Dockerfile` as you say, in Containter list this is running, but `localhost:3000` not working `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: what does docker ps say for PORTS of the container?

Comment: PORTS: 3000/tcp

Comment: I did`n understand what did am i wrong with EXPOSE, ports ;(

Comment: `Compiled successfully!


You can now view app in the browser.


Local: http://localhost:3000

On Your Network: http://172.17.0.2:3000`

Comment: Well did you publish your port with `docker run -P ... `  or alternatively `docker run -p 3000:3000 ... `

Comment: Wow, it WORKS! You big brainman!!! but why it not working with `EXPOSE 3000` and with key `-p 3000:3000` works hmmm...

Comment: Like written in the docs: `EXPOSE` in the dockerfile just tells the engine, this image has something running on port 3000. But `docker run` does not automatically bind that port to your local host. Probably for security reasons. So you have to explicitly bind your ports when running the container ...

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the WORKDIR, as the document says:

The **WORKDIR** instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, **COPY** and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile.

I think, saying just

```
COPY package.json
```

should be enough.

Comment: It didn't help (

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfiles don't have access to parent directories, unfortunately. However you can build the dockerfile from the parent directory by using `docker build -f path/to/dockerfile .`. Keep in mind that your `COPY` is relative to the directory you run the `docker build` from, which is the parent directory.

Also, `WORKDIR` uses/creates a directory **inside** the container. `WORKDIR /app` creates the 'app' folder in the root directory of the container, so `/../app` is unnecessary (although it achieves the same result).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference to parent directory in dockerfile for the reason explained in docker documentation:

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD
> ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is
> to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
> daemon.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

The easiest walk-around is:

```
docker build -t <some tag> -f <dir/dir/Dockerfile> .
```

Another thing you can add is build context. Instead of copying all files in the current directory to Docker Daemon, you can configure the context for example

```
docker build -t <some tag> -f ./dir/to/Dockerfile ./dir/to/build/context
```